# how to use angle bracket as a for /f delimiter

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

How do you use or escape greater than or less than sign as the delimiter in for /f loop?

I can't find the answer anywhere. Can somebody enlighten me?

Comment: How would you put any other character as delimiter??

Answer (score 3):

[`for /F` options](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) need to be [escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), i.e. (generally) surrounded in "quotes":

> `FOR /F`: Loop command against a set of files - conditionally perform
>   a command against each item.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
>     FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN (filenameset) DO command 
>
>     FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN ("Text string to process") DO command
> ```

However,  without surrounding  `options` in quotes, one need to escape delimiters (i.e. *comma* `,`, 
*semicolon* `;`,
*equals* `=`, 
*space*  and 
*tab* ) and cmd-poisonous characters (e.g. `<`,`>`,`|`,`&`) **severally**.

**Examples**:

```
==> for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=<> " %G in (" aa < bb > dd ") do @echo .%G.%H.%I.
.aa.bb.dd.

==> for /f tokens^=1^,2^,3^ delims^=^<^>^  %G in (" aa < bb > dd ") do @echo .%G.%H.%I.
.aa.bb.dd.

==> for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=<>" %G in (" aa < bb > dd ") do @echo .%G.%H.%I.
. aa . bb . dd .

==> for /f tokens^=1-3^ delims^=^<^>  %G in (" aa < bb > dd ") do @echo .%G.%H.%I.
. aa . bb . dd .

==>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
FOR /F "delims=<" %%parameter IN (filenameset) DO command
```

or

```
FOR /F "delims=>" %%parameter IN (filenameset) DO command
```

Comment: `for` options need to be put in quotes.